# Create Excel on the fly with share point

Tags: excel, sharepoint

Dears I need to create custom excel b share point, I write my code in web part so how I create file and return in response

Answer (score 0):

Shady.
Is there a scope of creating a CSV file, then you should create a CSV. Data is visible in different columns when you create a CSV.
If you want to create a excel, check if this blog helps :
https://www.thecodebuzz.com/read-excel-file-in-dotnet-core-2-1/